# How to properly simulate mining time with Ganache CLI

Tags: contract-development, testrpc, testing, ganache

I am using the Ganache CLI for testing my smart contracts and frontends. I need a way to incorporate a delay into ganache-cli when performing write transactions in order for it to more closely resemble the mainnet

I read that I should use the `-b` or `--blockTime` flag, however whenever launching ganache-cli with `-b 15`  my write transactions are still mined instantly.

Can anyone suggest the proper approach here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is the good one as far as i know. I've been using this option and it always worked.

However note that having a 15 seconds block doesn't mean that when you send your transaction it will be mined in 15 seconds, sometimes it will be less.

e.g : as last block was mined 9 seconds ago, next block should be mined in 6 seconds and chain receives a transaction, your transaction will be then executed in 6 seconds, even if option has been set to 15 seconds.

Have you tried chaining multiple transactions ?

If you still state that your transactions are computed instantly maybe you should open an issue on the ganache-cli repo, giving the information related to your environment, versions, etc.

Comment: I haven't tried changing multiple transactions. Just doing multiple writes with Web3 in one go?

Comment: Looks like -b is indeed the proper flag and there is an issue with the current build I was using. It works properly using the Ganache UI

Comment: I have not gotten this working with Ganache-cli, are you saying that I can start the UI with the same parameters as cli and get the desired result?
These parameters don't appear to be options in the settings menu when I run the UI.

Comment: i don't know as i never used anything else other than the CLI in my own case

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with ganache-cli. I just created an [issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/517) in their repo.

For now, switch to Ganache UI.

The accepted answer is misleading. As the OP acknowledges in the comment, he also ended up using Ganache UI.